# Foundation tabs are not displaying if data is being dynamically retrieved from the database

Tags: ajax, laravel, tabs, zurb-foundation

I have a vue js application that fetches data from a database using ajax and presents them in a foundation tab. I have emulated everything as best I know how but unfortunately the content is not appearing.

My Vue component code is as below.

```
<template>
    <section>
        <pos-header></pos-header>

        <div id="products">
            <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="product-types">
                <li class="tabs-title" v-for="type, index in products.types" :class="{ 'is-active': index == 0}">
                    <a :href="'#' + type.name">
                        {{ type.name }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="product-types">
                <div v-for="type, index in products.types" class="tabs-panel" :class="{ 'is-active': index == 0}" :id="type.name">
                    <p>Products</p>
                    <p>{{ index }} {{ type }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

import Header from './includes/Header.vue';

export default{
    data() {
        return {
            products: {
                types: []
            }
        }
    },

    components: {
        'pos-header': Header,
    },

    mounted(){

        let url = this.$store.getters.getApiUrl + '/product/types';

        axios.get(url).then( response => {
            this.products.types = response.data.productTypes;
            $(document).foundation();
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

The mounted method fetches the data and saves them in a data property called products types and I have ascertained that the items are being retrieved. This application is contained within a laravel application and laravel handles the backend api.

I should also add that i am able to see the links that change the tab content but the contents of the tabs are not displayed.

Comment: Do the foundation tabs you're referring to require some kind of Javascript to initialise them on document ready? If so you will need to fire this initialisation manually as the data won't be in the dom when 'onReady' is fired.

Comment: @joe ... Foundation does require javascript and I have initialized it. Its basically a substitute for bootstrap (if this info helps)

Comment: But at what point are you initialising it? If you're doing that before the fetched data is in the DOM it most likely won't work.

Comment: I am even running $(document).foundation() after setting the data. As shown in code. Thats the initialization code.